# Read file from Azure into MemoryStream C#

Tags: c#, azure

I have an ini config file located on Azure.  I don't want to download this file which is how its currently being handled.  I want to read it into a MemoryStream and parse it from there and then have the MemoryStream automatically flush the data.

Is there any way to do this without having to download the file itself onto the local drive?

Current download method is:

```
    myWebClient.DownloadFile("AzureLink", @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyProgram\\downloadedFile.ini")
```

Comment: What's your code for downloading it right now?

Comment: Please show us how you're performing the download at this time.

Comment: Amy and Tanveer, I've updated the original post

Comment: The type of `myWebClient`? It seems `HttpClient` to me.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a `WebClient`, and the OP just needs to switch to `DownloadData()`

Comment: @Amy had the correct answer.  Couldn't find that in the docs somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url))) 
{
    //your code in here
}
```